# What are the advantages of data formats like JSON/XML over key value pairs?

Tags: json, xml

Interview question : What are the advantages of data formats like JSON/XML over key value pairs  ?

Answer (score 2):

json/xml allows much more than key-value pairs. thats why they have an advantage!

You can represent arrays in json and also objects quite easily.
They are very easily read and can be used in various languages for serialization and transfer of objects between client/server or other end to end implementations.

Many languages has tools to interpret json objects to real program object vice-versa

Comment: Exactly.

A good question could be:
What are the advantages of data format JSON over XML?